# Value in a column unchanged for an hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time-series

I have a timestamp column and Mode column. Is there a way to check if the value in Mode column is 'RISK' unchanged for an hour?

[image]

Comment: please post your sample data as formatted string and not image. Also show the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . You can `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.mode = 'RISK' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.timestamp >= t.timestamp and
                        t2.timestamp < dateadd(hour, 1, t2.timestamp) and
                        t2.mode <> 'RISK'
                 );
```

Comment: Did you mean `t2.mode <> t.mode`? No explicit check for `t.mode = 'RISK'`?